Python remove duplicates from sorted array not working for [1,1,1,1]
LeetCode: Given an integer array nums sorted in non-decreasing order, remove the duplicates in-place such that each unique element appears only once.
My code works for all of the test cases so far, except [1, 1, 1, 1]. In that case, it is only going to [1, 1] and not removing the duplicate 1
def removedup(nums):
    for n in nums:
        if nums.count(n) > 1:
            nums.remove(n)
    return(nums)

removedup([1,1,2]) #works
removedup([1,1,1,1]) #doesnt work 


Your code doesn't take any advantage of the fact that the list is sorted. That should be a hint that you're not doing it right.

Your code will fail for any case where the sequence of duplicates has at least 4 elements.

Don't mutate your list while you iterate over it. Instead, use a Python set and build a new list, e.g.:
def removedup_v2(nums):
    s = set()
    o = []
    for n in nums:
        if n not in s:
            s.add(n)
            o.append(n)
    return(o)


@AlexReynolds The instructions specifically say "in-place".

Rule #1, in any language: don't modify the sequence you're iterating over.

@AlexReynolds Why so complicated? Just do nums[:] = {*nums}.

@Barmar I might take advantage of the sortedness by using while instead of if :-)

I don't see how that takes advantage. What you can do is search for the index of the next element that's greater than the current element, then remove the slice between them.

@Barmar The advantage is that the sortedness makes that work correctly.

Why do you think it wouldn't work? You still need to get rid of the for loop, because it's skipping elements when you remove in place.

What you want is something like while nums.count(nums[i]) > 1: but that doesn't use sortedness.

@Barmar Well ok, it would also work for some unsorted lists, but not for example for [1,2,1,3,2,3]. And no, I'm not getting rid of the for loop. I really meant purely changing if to while, no other changes. Thanks to the sortedness, the value that gets "skipped" is the last occurrence of the value we just made unique. Which is ok. Demo.

I guess you're right. But you're turning this into an N^3 algorithm due to the repeated calls to nums.count(). Since nums.count() tells you how many duplicates there are, and you know they're consecutive, you could just delete count-1 elements.

That's what I meant by "take advantage" -- it allows you to make the algorithm more efficient, not just correct.

@Barmar Nah it's N^2.

@nocomment for n in nums: is O(n). while nums.count(n) > 1 is O(n). And nums.remove(n) is O(n). Put together it's O(n^3).

@Barmar It's O(n^2). I'm really surprised you're not familiar with this and don't see it. You think you can n times do n removes? A total of n^2 removes? From a list of n elements? No you can't.
